# Property of a differentiable function F verifying $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ :[0,1]→R   be a differentiable function such as that $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$.
For some natural number $n$ >$1$

Prove that for some $0$$<$ $x_1$ $<$ $x_2$ $<$ ... $<$ $x_n$<$1$
$\sum_{i=1}^n F'(x_i$)=n
I've been having trouble with this exercice it seemed easy at first but I couldn't make any progress.

Comment: Shouldn't $x_1=0$ & $x_n = 1$?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy If so, then it would be false.

Comment: Darboux Theorem tells us that for all $\;c\in (0,1)\;$ there exists $\;c'\in (0,1)\;$ s.t. $\;F'(c')=c\;$ (derivative of real functions has the intermediate value property). Thus the problem can be reduced to first show there exist $\;n\;$ points in $\;(0,1)\;$ whose sum equals $\;n\;$

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've rechecked and it says $0<x_1$ and $x_n<1$

Comment: @DonAntonio It sounds like you're assuming $F'(0) = 0, F'(1) = 1$ instead of $F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1$ (though you can use the same idea to make it work)

Comment: On that note, Lazarus, do you have access to [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))?  If so, use it.  First consider the case where $F(x) = x$ (when the proof is immediate) and then consider the case of $F(c) < c$ for some $0 < c < 1,$ where we use the mean value theorem along with Darboux's theorem.  (The last case of $F(c) > c$ for some $0 < c < 1$ is done similarly)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Indeed so, thanx. It wasn't that immediate but we still can make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0\le i\le n$, let $a_i=\frac in$. For $1\le i\le n$, apply the Mean Value Theorem to $[a_{i-1},a_{i}]$

> to find $x_i\in(a_{i-1},a_{i})$ with  $$F'(x_i)=\frac{F(a_{i})-F(a_{i-1})}{a_{i}-a_{i-1}}=n(F(a_{i})-F(a_{i-1})).$$

This guarantees

> $$0<x_1<\frac 1n<x_2<\ldots <\frac{n-1}n<x_n<1 $$ and $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n F'(x_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^nn(F(a_{i})-F(a_{i-1}))\\&=n\sum_{i=1}^nF(a_{i})-n\sum_{i=1}^nF(a_{i-1})\\&=nF(1)-nF(0)\\&=n\end{align}$$